# Stream content of a url that is secure

Tags: java, session, stream, httpurlconnection

I am trying to stream content of a URL that is secure. The URL is accessible only after you login with username or password. When you are not logged in, you will be redirected to login.jsp. How can I stream such a URL? Is there a way to maintain session? I want to stream and store that content in file system. I cannot even provide password using Apache httpClient authentication because the passwords are one-way encrypted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you are logged in, do you have a cookie that indicates that you have a session? You can pass that cookie.

Comment: Yup it worked. This is the code I used.                               
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + request.getSession().getId() + "; rememberMe=false");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the Cookie as David Conrad suggested, I got it working using the following code sample.
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + request.getSession().getId() + "; rememberMe=false")